# what does this X = [0, 1] × Q mean in terms of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I wanted someone to explain what this notation means.

I am of the understanding that [0,1] includes only zero and one and not the range of real numbers between these two numbers. I would like some clarification on this.

Comment: It does include the "range" you mention. for example $( \sqrt{2}/10, 19/2)$ belongs to your set.

Comment: $\{0, 1\}$ includes only 0 and 1.  Braces are used to denote a list of elements of a set, or to define a set: e.g. $\{2n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ to denote even natural numbers.  But $[0, 1]$ denotes an interval on the real number line of all real numbers between 0 and 1, and includes $0,1$ as well, and the interval is itself a subset of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the set $[a,b]=\{x\in \mathbb{R} \ | \ a\leq x\leq b\}.$ In your case $[0,1]$ therefore denotes the set of all real numbers including and between $0$ and $1$. If one is performing the cross product of sets $[0,1]\times \mathbb{Q}$, then this contains a pair $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x\in [0,1]$ and $y\in\mathbb{Q}$. So as someone has mentioned, the point $(\sqrt{2}/10,19/2)$ would belong in the set $[0,1]\times \mathbb{Q}$.

I hope that this helps but please don't hesitate to ask more questions!